Concatenate list of strings into phrase with no comma before last string and with "and"/"or" before last string
If I have a list of strings such as {"A", "B", "C", "D"}, what's the cleanest code for dynamically concatenating them into a phrase without a comma before the last string and with an "and" or an "or" before the last string?
For example:
if I have {"A"}, it should output "A"
if I have {"A","B"}, it should output "A or B"
if I have {"A","B","C"}, it should output "A, B or C"

I would slice the list into the "last element" and "everything else". Join "everything else" with string.Join and add the "last element" at the end. The edge cases are when the list only has one or no elements.
string Concatenate(List<string> strings) {
    if (strings.Count < 2) {
        return strings.FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
    } else {
        return $"{string.Join(", ", strings[..^1])} or {strings[^1]}";
    }
}


This is how I did it in C#, I'm not sure it's the cleanest but tested to work for each scenario above:
var listOfStrings = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
// replace with "and" if needed
var concatenatorPhrase = "or";
var fullPhrase = new StringBuilder();
var firstString = listOfStrings.First();
listOfStrings.Remove(firstString);
fullPhrase.Append(firstString);
if (listOfStrings.Count > 0)
{
    var lastString = listOfStrings.Last();
    listOfStrings.Remove(lastString);

    if (listOfStrings.Count > 0)
    {
        fullPhrase.Append(", ");
        foreach (var str in listOfStrings)
        {
            fullPhrase.Append(str).Append(", ");
        }
    }

    fullPhrase.Append($"{concatenatorPhrase} ").Append(lastString);
}
fullPhrase.ToString()


How about this:
    private static string CustomConcatenate(List<string> inputList)
    {
        var lengthOfList = inputList.Count;
        var listWithSeparators = inputList
            .Select((s, i) => ((i == 0) ? string.Empty : (i == lengthOfList - 1) ? " or " : ", ") + s);
        return string.Join("", listWithSeparators);
    }
    
// XUnit test case just to verify whether the function gives expected result or not
    [Fact] 
    public void ConcatTest()
    {
        var givenLstWithMoreThan2Elmts = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
        "A, B or C".Should().Be(CustomConcatenate(givenLstWithMoreThan2Elmts));
    
        // 2nd case
        var givenLstWith2Elmts = new List<string> { "A", "B" };
        "A or B".Should().Be(CustomConcatenate(givenLstWith2Elmts));
    
        // 3rd case
        var givenLst3 = new List<string> { "A" };
        "A".Should().Be(CustomConcatenate(givenLst3));
    }


string[][] strings =
[
  ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
  ["A", "B", "C"],
  ["A", "B"],
  ["A"]
];
foreach (var arr in strings)
{
  string s = string.Join("", arr.Select((s, index) => s + arr.Count() switch
  {
    1 => "",
    _ => (index == arr.Count() - 1) ? "" : (index == arr.Count() - 2) ? " or " : ", "
  }));
  Console.WriteLine(s);
}

// Output:
// A, B, C or D
// A, B or C
// A or B
// A


Because no question like this is complete without someone offering a regex option :
Regex.Replace(string.Join(", ", list), ", (?=[^,]*$)", " or ");

In essence this looks for a comma followed by any number of anything that is not a comma but only at the end of the string.
Only the comma is replaced, because we used a positive look ahead to find the other characters to ensure we matched the last comma, but the characters found by positive look ahead don't form part of the match that is replaced
Note, I doubt this approach is going to be as performant or developer friendly as other approaches - perhaps an education piece but always seek to write code that is easy for others on the team to understand. If you use it, consider adding a comment for how the regex works etc
